# Сортировка массива методом деления отрезков пополам

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Мне нужно написать домашнее задание для знакомого в инст.
Он практически ничего не понимает.
Нужно сделать правильно.

Задание простое на сортировку. Говорит, что нужно использовать PHP.
Правильно ли понимаю? Решение которое сделал ниже.

[image]

Правильно ли понимаю:

1. "**Графически продемонстрировать метод решения**". Это не визуализатор с анимацией, а просто текст, который по шагам демонстрирует решение?
2. **"Построить схему основных процедур, функций, классов, объектов  и показать  их взаимосвязь"**, UML диаграмму нарисовать и распечатать или что?
3. **"Указать основные ошибки отладки и тестирования программы"** - не понимаю. Мне нужно рассказать историю того, что мне интерпретатор на экран выводил("синтаксическая ошибка в строке 17")?
4. **"Список использованной литературы."** - а здесь что? 
   Можно ли привести книги?
   "PHP за 24 часа"
   "PHP для хакера"
   "PHP для чайника"

**Варианты:**
№2 нужно сделать.
Правильно ли понимаю?

Использован метод сортировки бисекции(метод деления отрезка пополам), подходящий для вставки элемента в уже отсортированный массив.

1. Массив уже отсортирован по возрастанию. 30 элементов, от 1 до 30.
2. Вставляю случайное число 14.
3. Сравниваю с первым элементом, если число больше, то делю на половину отрезок между текущим и еще не проверяемым.
4. 14 > 1
5. 14 < 15
6. 14 > 7
7. 14 > 11
8. 14 > 13
9. 14 == 14

Необходимо осуществить вставку после элемента массива под индексом 14.
Время поиска логарифмическое.
Было выполнено 6 операций сравнений.

Comment: А по решению, я всё правильно понимаю?
Там в конце, где сравниваю элементы?

Comment: честно говоря, не знаю, что за "метод деления отрезка пополам" (название больше походит на геометрию), однако выглядит это как бинарный поиск (и на первый взгляд описано верно) 

И вообще эта зацикленность на "бумажных" вопросах типа списка литературы и описания ошибок несколько настораживает - задача выглядит как обычная лабораторная работа, вряд ли она достойна такого внимания к сопутствующим ей деталям

Comment: Точно "бинарный поиск, двоичный поиск". Совсем забыл. Хорошо. Спасибо. 
Как сделаю покажу как выглядит вывод от php.

Comment: Сделал. Примерно так и надо или как?

Ссылка на [код][1]

[Здесь][2] можно проверить код онлайн:


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eGds5dBaHOrA_YtrpoyC6B821sZkNvBbbps1w781IVg/pub
  [2]: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не факт. Особенно с замахом на web-приложение.
   Но текстовый вариант должен подойти.
2. Да. И не обязательно UML. В некоторых местах схемки любят.
3. Нет. Имеются в виду логические ошибки, типа не учёл вот такой случай.
4. Список литературы везде нужен. Любые подходящие источники по алгоритмам. По языку тоже можно - хуже не будет, но на алгоритмы надо обязательно.

№2 - Да, понимаешь правильно. Бинпоиск теоретически подойдёт, но это бессмысленно. Массив - это непрерывный участок памяти и чтобы что-то вставить в середину, надо двигать хвост. Поэтому тупо идти с хвоста и сдвигать все элементы большие вставляемого. Когда элемент окажется меньше или равен, либо будет достигнут конец массива, прекратить сдвигание и записать на свободную позицию вставляемый элемент. Это если массив предполагает возможность изменения размера. Если нет, то создать новый массив, копировать в него элементы, меньшие вставляемого, затем его самого и хвост оригинального массива. И никакого бинпоиска.